# Why objects must be serialized before being passed to activities in android?

Tags: android, data-structures, android-intent

In order to pass an object to an `Activity`, object must implement `Parcelable`/`Serializable` (or JSON-encoded, or whatever casts the object to a scalar).

(I know the [alternative](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3) of using singletons, statics and so on.)

Why it is not possible to give a POJO to my `Activity`, something like `new Intent( ... , myObject)` or `startActivity(intent, myObject)` ?

Comment: Your call to `startActivity` is passed through to `ActivityManagerNative` - which, in turn, communicates with the activity manager service that runs in a completely different process - thus forcing whatever you put in your `Intent` to be `Parcelable` or `Serializable`.

Answer (score 1):

I turned @Jens's comment into a community wiki:

Your call to `startActivity` is passed through to `ActivityManagerNative` - which, in turn, communicates with the activity manager service that runs in a completely different process - thus forcing whatever you put in your `Intent` to be `Parcelable` or `Serializable`